# Confusion on center of movement while tilting a floating body

Tags: classical-mechanics, buoyancy

When a floating body is tilted at an angle $\theta$, the restoring moment will be about the [metacenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacentric_height). But is the tilting movement about the center of gravity?

If it is, then it looks like there would be a drag because the two points may be different. So is the tilting movement also centered on the metacenter?

The general rule for the object not to sink, as shown in an [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJE1VPb4PGc) is the following

Moment due to increased weight = Moment due to change in center of buoyancy

[image]

However if we already know $V$ the volume of the increased triangle and we compute $B_{1}$ then we can equate the RHS and LHS without computing $\frac{I}{V}$.

Also in our case $\theta$ is not so small. So we do not cancel out $\theta$. So can we just compute the weight as $V \rho g$ (weight of the **triangular** strip) and equate its moment with the RHS will we get the same effect ?

But if the tilt is not about the C.O.G. then the calculation of V changes.